# How to Create a Custom Appender in log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

As disscussed in this link : [How to create a own Appender in log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072389/how-to-create-a-own-appender-in-log4j)

For creating a custom appender in log4j 1.x we have to extend the AppenderSkeleton class and implements its append method.

Similarly How we can create a custom appender in log4j2 as we dont have AppenderSkelton class to extend and all other appender extend AppenderBase class .

Answer (score 97, accepted):

This works quite differently in log4j2 than in log4j-1.2.

In log4j2, you would create a plugin for this. The manual has an explanation with an example for a custom appender here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Appenders

It may be convenient to extend `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender`, but this is not required.

When you annotate your custom Appender class with `@Plugin(name="MyCustomAppender", ....`, the plugin name becomes the configuration element name, so a configuration with your custom appender would then look like this:

```
<Configuration packages="com.yourcompany.yourcustomappenderpackage">
  <Appenders>
    <MyCustomAppender name="ABC" otherAttribute="...">
    ...
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers><Root><AppenderRef ref="ABC" /></Root></Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Note that the `packages` attribute on the configuration is a comma-separated list of all the packages with custom log4j2 plugins. Log4j2 will search these packages in the classpath for classes annotated with @Plugin.

Here is a sample custom appender that prints to the console:

```
package com.yourcompany.yourcustomappenderpackage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;

// note: class name need not match the @Plugin name.
@Plugin(name="MyCustomAppender", category="Core", elementType="appender", printObject=true)
public final class MyCustomAppenderImpl extends AbstractAppender {

    private final ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock readLock = rwLock.readLock();

    protected MyCustomAppenderImpl(String name, Filter filter,
            Layout<? extends Serializable> layout, final boolean ignoreExceptions) {
        super(name, filter, layout, ignoreExceptions);
    }

    // The append method is where the appender does the work.
    // Given a log event, you are free to do with it what you want.
    // This example demonstrates:
    // 1. Concurrency: this method may be called by multiple threads concurrently
    // 2. How to use layouts
    // 3. Error handling
    @Override
    public void append(LogEvent event) {
        readLock.lock();
        try {
            final byte[] bytes = getLayout().toByteArray(event);
            System.out.write(bytes);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (!ignoreExceptions()) {
                throw new AppenderLoggingException(ex);
            }
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    // Your custom appender needs to declare a factory method
    // annotated with `@PluginFactory`. Log4j will parse the configuration
    // and call this factory method to construct an appender instance with
    // the configured attributes.
    @PluginFactory
    public static MyCustomAppenderImpl createAppender(
            @PluginAttribute("name") String name,
            @PluginElement("Layout") Layout<? extends Serializable> layout,
            @PluginElement("Filter") final Filter filter,
            @PluginAttribute("otherAttribute") String otherAttribute) {
        if (name == null) {
            LOGGER.error("No name provided for MyCustomAppenderImpl");
            return null;
        }
        if (layout == null) {
            layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout();
        }
        return new MyCustomAppenderImpl(name, filter, layout, true);
    }
}
```

For more details on plugins:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html

If the manual is not enough, it may be useful to look at the source code for the built-in appenders in log4j-core.

Comment: It looks like plugin appenders are scanned at startup and *cannot* be added during runtime. Is that true? If so, this does not answer the question of how to programmatically alter Log4J 2 behavior.

Comment: @ingyhere Programmatically configuring Log4j2 is indeed a separate question. This log4j2 manual page may be a good starting point to find out more: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#AddingToCurrent Otherwise you may want to ask a new question.

Comment: @Remko I'm bit confused then how it would be detected as a Console apernder, File appender etc. As an example if I want to print into console using a custom appender how could I do this ? Thanks!

Comment: It's help a lot,I want to send logs to web services.then what can I do. Thanks Remko

Comment: @Remko Why do we need to use readLock lock and unlock method inside the doAppend method of the custom appender? How purpose does it serves here?

Comment: The lock is not necessary if the layout implementation is threadsafe (most if not all built-in Log4j2 layouts are thread safe).

Comment: @RemkoPopma Can you please clarify more on layout implementation being thread safe? We currently use log4j PatternLayout in our implementation. Moreover, does the use of readLock lock and unlock method inside the doAppend method makes it synchronous i.e. only one thread can write to the appender at a time?

Comment: Log4j2's PatternLayout is thread safe and doesn't require locking. Yes, the use of the lock makes the appender synchronous. If your appender writes the resulting bytes to some threadsafe destination then your appender doesn't need to do locking.

Comment: @Aman multiple threads are allowed to acquire the same read lock. Since nothing ever acquires the associated write lock, those `lock` / `unlock` calls don't do anything. This code isn't thread-safe, and multiple threads can execute the guarded code simultaneously.

Comment: createAppender() is deprecated in 2.7 can someone add an example of @PluginBuilderFactory

Comment: @RemkoPopma: what about methods vosid start() and void stop() from LifeCycle interface. When they are called? I am asking, as for me stop() is very important, as I need to deallocate some resources (not memory). Additionally I see my Appender is created 3 times in startup and every time it has another configuration, so I need to stop previous instance and start new one.

Comment: @SewerynHabdank-Wojewódzki It may be better to ask on the Log4j user mailing list or raise a JIRA ticket if the Appender being created 3 times looks like a bug.

Comment: @RemkoPopma thanks for post. For people looking for an answer, I upgraded a large app from log4j v1 to v2 and needed to modify RollingFileAppender behavior to do some extra actions on startup. The way to achieve that was "cloning" the provided `RollingFileAppender` class and coding what I needed in it. Their provided one is a final class, so can't be extended.

Comment: @cbaldan, glad to hear this helped. Note that if you only need to write something to the file on rollover, the [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) has a `header` and `footer` attribute that may be useful. But it may be useful to raise this topic of custom actions on the log4j-dev mailing list.

Answer (score 5):

As you pointed out AppenderSkeleton is not available anymore so the solutions in [How to create my own Appender in log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072389/how-to-create-my-own-appender-in-log4j) will not work.

Using Mockito, or similar library to create an Appender with an ArgumentCaptor will not work if you're expecting multiple logging messages because the MutableLogEvent is reused over multiple log messages.

The most generic solution I found for log4j2 is to provide a mock implementation that records all the messages. It does not require any additional libraries like Mockito or JMockit.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender;    

private static MockedAppender mockedAppender;
private static Logger logger;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockedAppender.message.clear();
}

/**
 * For some reason mvn test will not work if this is @Before, but in eclipse it works! As a
 * result, we use @BeforeClass.
 */
@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    mockedAppender = new MockedAppender();
    logger = (Logger)LogManager.getLogger(ClassWithLoggingToTest.class);
    logger.addAppender(mockedAppender);
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
}

@AfterClass
public static void teardown() {
    logger.removeAppender(mockedAppender);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    // do something that causes logs
    for (String e : mockedAppender.message) {
        // add asserts for the log messages
    }
}

private static class MockedAppender extends AbstractAppender {

    List<String> message = new ArrayList<>();

    protected MockedAppender() {
        super("MockedAppender", null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void append(LogEvent event) {
        message.add(event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been the most helpful and the working example for me with Kotlin. Thanks @joseph for taking the time by including the package names, that helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

> It looks like plugin appenders are scanned at startup and cannot be added during runtime. Is that true?

to add new appender while running you can use monitorInterval property to update log configuration i.e. every 60 sec:

```
    <Configuration monitorInterval="60">
```

Comment: You can programatically add an Appender but if monitorInterval is set then the added appender will be lost if changes are made to the configuration file.