# How to include Log4j2 messages in TestNG reporting

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng, log4j2

I would like to have the Log4j2 logging information available in the TestNG reports for all of the test cases.

TestNG uses a special logger class called Reporter.java that keeps track of the log output and saves it in its results XML.

In log4j it was possible to simply create an appender implementation that routes to Reporter and register it.

With the new Logger API in Log4j2 it has been difficult to find information on how to accomplish this. I have some information to get this done using Log4j but not with Log4j2.

Comment: Did you google it? http://goo.gl/UyUqN4

Comment: @rinuthomaz log4j2 does not seem to be the question. Integration with testng does.

Comment: please be specific with test report, like what test report ?

Comment: looks like this SO answer might have what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36210968/2234770

Comment: This explains how to create a new log file with log4j I have already done this. Though the look was very appricated @DavidHoliday

Comment: @rinuthomaz TestNG has a special logger that when messages are sent to it.. they are recorded automatically. Since both the OP and myself are trying to use other features of Log4j in conjunction with our tests we need this integration point.

Comment: This answer might be of interest to you: [how to create a custom appender in log4j2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205093/how-to-create-a-custom-appender-in-log4j2).

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell you just need to implement a simple Appender. Something like:

```
@Plugin(name="Reporter", category ="Core", elementType="appender", printObject=true)
public class ReporterAppender extends AbstractAppender {

    private ReporterAppender(final String name, final Layout layout) {
        super(name, null, layout, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void append(final LogEvent event) {
        final Layout<? extends Serializable> layout = getLayout();
        if (layout != null && layout instanceof AbstractStringLayout) {
             Reporter.log(((AbstractStringLayout) layout).toSerializable(event));
        } else {
             Reporter.log(event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage();            }

    @PluginFactory
    public static ReporterAppender createAppender(
        @PluginAttribute("name") @Required(message = "A name for the Appender must be specified") final String name,
        @PluginElement("Layout") Layout<? extends Serializable> layout) {
        return new ReporterAppender(name, layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, Ralph's answer deserves the bonus.

Comment: great answer. but if anyone facing compilation issue for above code , then just fix line Reporter.log(event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage();            } to correct one as Reporter.log(event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage());}} // method cosing

Answer (score -2):

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

add this in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

then you can use log.info or log.error etc...

Comment: question is about log4j2

Comment: ohhh I thought both are same... sorry