# log4j2 Custom kafka Appender plugin ignored

Tags: java, log4j2

I have created a custom log4j2 Kafka appender as I need to send the message in protocol buffers format. When I run the application, I see the following warning. How to make the custom appender override the default appender?

*Plugin [kafka] is already mapped to class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.kafka.KafkaAppender, ignoring class com.abc.appender.KafkaAppender*

NOTE: I have read the documentation in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html and it is not clear how to set the plugin override order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your custom plugin to have a different name. That should resolve the problem.

Comment: [Remko Popma](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1446916/remko-popma) - Thanks for the clarification!! I will try this approach and let you know.

Comment: [Remko Popma](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1446916/remko-popma) - Your advice helped. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share Custom Class Code

Comment: One example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24220688/1446916