# log4j not using third-party appender (SumoLogic) when executing the main app via a fat jar

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I use the `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin to compile a fat jar. I have `log4j2` and these dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sumologic.plugins.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>sumologic-log4j2-appender</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I configure the logger in the log4j XML configuration file, I specify the SumoAppender and a console output appender.

When I run the main app via `mvn exec:java` the SumoLogic appender works.

However when I compile a fat jar and run the app via `java -jar fatjar.jar`, the SumoLogic Appender doesn't run at all, and there is no error that gets output.

I checked that the class exists in my app using `Class.forName("com.sumologic.log4j.SumoLogicAppender")` and the package indeed exists.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue - in my case mvn camel:run worked fine, but java -jar did not.

Adding the sumologic package to the log4j2 configuration file did the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="com.sumologic.log4j">
<Appenders>
<SumoLogicAppender
....
```

Same strategy as when creating custom appenders - [How to Create a Custom Appender in log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205093/how-to-create-a-custom-appender-in-log4j2)