# Log4j Migration - How to migrate Custom File Appender with log4j bridge or logj2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I have one customer appender class that was implemented in log4j 1 as below:

```
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter;
import org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog;
...

public class CustomFileAppender extends FileAppender
{
    ...
    @Override
    protected void setQWForFiles(final Writer writer)
    {
        super.qw = new CountingQuietWriter(writer, super.errorHandler);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to migrate this class to use bridge (log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1) (and log4j 2 core and api version 2.17.1)

I noticed that:

1> The Log4j bridge does not have FileApennder class. The [migration doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) did list the FileAppender as one of the supported components

2> log4j 2 File appender cannot be extend as the class is defined as "public final class FileAppender"

My questions are:

1> What is the best way to migrate custom File Appender in this case?

2> What is the equivalent of below classes in log4j2?

- org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
- org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter
- org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog

Comment: But in logj4 bridge for 2.22,  there is org.apache.log4j.FileAppender in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

log4j2 and the bridge do not contain the classes that log4j1 custom appenders used to extend, therefore you must consider rewriting your custom appender as a new log4j2 plugin. You can get some information from [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html) and [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html).
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205093/how-to-create-a-custom-appender-in-log4j2) also can give you some inspiration.

Comment: Version 2.17.2 will contain about 50 improvements in the Log4j 1.x bridge, among them some old classes like `org.apache.log4j.FileAppender`.