# log4j2 configuration not being applied when custom class loading

Tags: java, log4j2, classloader

I have a Java application (= launcher) which loads classes via a custom [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). In my launched application as well as in the launcher I'm using [`log4j2`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j) with a custom XML configuration.

In the launcher:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER;

static
{
    loadLog4jConfiguration(ApplicationLauncherClient.class);
    LOGGER = getLogger();
}
```

`loadLog4jConfiguration()` is implemented as follows:

```
public static void loadLog4jConfiguration(final Class<?> clazz)
{
    try
    {
        String resourceName = "launcher-log4j2.xml";
        try (InputStream inputStream = clazz.getResourceAsStream(resourceName))
        {
            if (inputStream == null)
            {
                System.err.println("Cannot find resource: " + resourceName);
            } else
            {
                ConfigurationSource configurationSource = new ConfigurationSource(inputStream);
                Configurator.initialize(null, configurationSource);
            }
        }
    } catch (final Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the launched application I do the same setup for `log4j2` but I load a *different* `log4j2.xml` file from the classpath (e.g. [to provide `JTextArea` appending of log messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005748)).

Unfortunately, the `JTextArea` logs do not work when custom classloading. They work however when I launch the application normally (e.g. via IDE). I assume there is some sort of clash between `log4j2` instances. The launcher and the launched application hold the `log4j2` maven dependency. How would I resolve this cleanly? I do not want to remove `log4j2` from the launcher entirely. I thought about maybe always passing a class instance into the `getLogger()` constructor on the launched application but that didn't help either. I printed out the `ClassLoader` of the `LOGGER` instance on the launched application and it said `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` in both cases (when custom classloading and when launching it normally via the IDE) so now I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Configurator.reconfigure(URI)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.